# activate a worksheet by name in a list

Tags: worksheet

Each of my worksheets represents a Project
In the first worksheet ("Select Project") I have created a list that contains all worksheets names (Cells A3:A50)
In a specific cell( E4), in this worksheet, I select a project from the list
I wish to activate the worksheet with that name (of cell E4)

Comment: What did you try. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your "Select Project" VBA module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("E4")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim projectName As Variant
        projectName = [E4]
        Sheets(projectName).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

This event handler (triggered when any value in your "Select Project" sheet is changed) will check if it was the cell E4, which was changed and if so, it activates the sheet based on the value in this cell.